# sending URL with special characters through Http (android)

Tags: json, http, url

I'm trying to execute an URL that will pass two parameters of location coordinates that include a comma (",") but the url is being fetched differently (without the comma) therefore the webservice is returning null.

```
new JSONTask2().execute("http://server/WEService.svc/sendloc/56/39,911437/32,809107");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%2c` in the URL to replace the commas.

With your URL being dynamic, you can use `url = url.replace(",", "%2c");`

Comment: but the location will be a variable so i can not do that. the url is just an example

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how you can replace a part of a string.